# Javascript 10 lines on a canvas on click tell which one was clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have to draw on a canvas 10 random lines with 10 random color. If I click on one line I have print out the order of the line and the color of the line. How to solve this?

[Problem representation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buher.jpg)

E1: Another question is, that how can I get the canvas color on a specific X,Y coordinate?

Comment: Can u show us ur code?

Comment: I haven't write it yet, because I don't know how to start, I'm totally new in JS. I was thinking only about to get the pixel color where it was clicked, I asked this question to get a better idea.

Comment: You should show your effort when asking a question on SO.

Comment: I did not know that I can ask a question only if I tried something. I try to manage to solve this, but until that can I leave this post open, and I will edit with my post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw the lines with 10 random positions and colours, use `Math.random();`, and of course the `<canvas>` element.
And to get the cursor position, use the `element.clientX` and `element.clientY` proprieties.
HTML:

```
<canvas id="_canvas"></canvas>
```

And the JavaScript code will do all the job, read the comments:

```
var element = document.getElementById('_canvas'); //Get the element
var ctx = element.getContext("2d");               //...And its context...

var cols = [];                                    //Whoah! The array where the colors will be stored in.

let width = element.offsetWidth;                  //Get the width of the canvas,
let height = element.offsetHeight;                //And the height!

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);        //Get a random color for the line, the red value,
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);        //Green,
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);        //And blue.

  r = parseInt(r);                                //Remove decimal numbers.
  g = parseInt(g);
  b = parseInt(b);

   var rgbToHex = function (rgb) {                //And this function converts RGB to HEX!
    var hex = Number(rgb).toString(16);
    if (hex.length < 2) {
         hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex;
  };

  var fullColorHex = function(r,g,b) {           //I mean this function converts RGB to HEX, but... anyway...
    var red = rgbToHex(r);
    var green = rgbToHex(g);
    var blue = rgbToHex(b);
    return red+green+blue;
  };

  let hexval = "#" + fullColorHex(r, g, b);     //Now convert our RGB value to a hexadecimal number and add a "sharp" to the beginning of it!

  ctx.beginPath();                              //Alright now the serious stuff, begin painting.

  ctx.moveTo(Math.random() * (+width - +0) + +0, Math.random() * (+height - +0) + +0); //From a random position,
  ctx.lineTo(Math.random() * (+width - +0) + +0, Math.random() * (+height - +0) + +0); //To a random position!
  ctx.strokeStyle = hexval;                                                            //change the line's color.
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;                                                                   //Change the strength of the lines, they will look insane but you will never click on them without this.

  cols.push(hexval.replace("#", ""));

  ctx.stroke();                                                                        //Draw it!
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target == element) {                                                            //Does the user click on the canvas?
    var x = e.clientX;                                                                 //Get the mouse position
    var y = e.clientY;

    var c = element.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; 
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + fullColorHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);             //Get the color of the pixel!
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log("Colors: " + cols[i] + ", hex: " + hex);
      if("#" + cols[i] == hex) {
        alert("Order: " + i + ", color: " + hex);                                      //Done!
      }
    }
  }
};
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/MWwMyog?editors=0010